# Rake db:migrate aborted! Ghost development database using MySQL2?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

OK, I just re-installed MySQL Servers 5.5(32bit to 64bit) on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. I then took the steps to use mysql2 for rails:

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6'
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
```

Step 1:

```
rake db:drop
Couldn't drop store_development : #<Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'store_development'>
```

Strange because in the MySQL Workbench I only see the test database up.

Step 2:

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Unknown database 'store_development'
```

No idea why I get this error so I try to reset the database now.

Step 3:

```
rake db:reset
(in C:/store)
Couldn't drop store_development : #<Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'store_development'>
store_test already exists
-- create_table("business_online_stores", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.1110s
-- create_table("business_retail_stores", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0740s
-- create_table("businesses", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0900s
-- create_table("products", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0810s
-- create_table("user_prices", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0720s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.1810s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.2800s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(0, "db/migrate")
   -> 0.0320s
You have 6 pending migrations:
  20110909175650 DeviseCreateUsers
  20110929161120 CreateUserPrices
  20111004023516 CreateProducts
  20111007023521 CreateBusinesses
  20111009215120 CreateBusinessRetailStores
  20111009215419 CreateBusinessOnlineStores
Run "rake db:migrate" to update your database then try again.
```

Yes, the Test database does already exist but where is this Ghost development database at? How does it reset the migrations, yet tell me to migrate them again. Ok, ill do as it says now:

Step 4:

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in C:/store)
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users`
```

Step 5:

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Unknown database 'store_development'
```

Impossible, I went inside of my MySQL Workbench and dropped the test and development databases by right-clicking them and going through the necessary steps so nothing exist even when I refresh it, yet I get this error about a database that doesn't exist.

How do I fix this problem?

Note:  `0.2.7`  Gives me the same issues.

Note: These are my first 2 migration files just encase anyone wanted to see them: https://gist.github.com/1341682

Comment: can you please show the migration file for users and the one following it.

Comment: @Ross Ok, I put it in the gist link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this that I know of was to recreate my whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but does `Users` already have entries in the email column?  I wonder if an existing duplicate entry would prevent the addition of the validation `:unique=>true`

And just to check, did you want to do?:

```
add_column :users, :email, :string
```

instead of add_index?

Comment: As of right now It doesn't have any entries that I know of. Is their a way to find out? I just installed MySQL server and am brand new to it so I couldn't be 100% sure. No, I am trying to add_index since when I try to seed, it said I had 6 pending migrations which is the total amount of migrations in my application right now. If it helps I am using the Devise gem for user authentication, running it fresh off the gem.

Comment: Oh.  If you want to just drop Users, try: rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20111106043251  ... where VERSION equals the timestamp appended to the migration file you named 'DeviseCreateUsers'

Comment: Looks like it would be: rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20110909175650 in this case.

Comment: The issue has changed, now I get a ghost database. Take a look at my question now, its pretty different but deals with the same problem.

Comment: Sorry.  Am now out of my depth here.  I am about to make my first stab at migrating a Rails app to a production server.  I expect I will use Phusion Passenger to ease the way.  Perhaps it too would simplify matters in your case?  Link to P.P. is here: http://www.modrails.com/